# Angular2 http error vs success response, coming from Express

Tags: json, angular, express

I am wondering as to the why and the what to do about the success vs error response being handled differently by Angular2's http module.

Example call:

```
http.post(url, payload).map(response => response.json()).toPromise()
```

I then call .then on the promise and route to a success or err function, piping the output to console. My issue/question is, the response gets all kinda and json formatted for me as an object during success, but for error I get the big gnarly full html response. I want to be able to access the "errorMessageToUser" which is attached to the _body of the response in my below example. What's the best way to accomplish?

```
.then(
  success => console.log("success", success),
  err => console.log("error", err))
```

And here's the code in Express that generates the error in this example

```
return res.status(401).json({ errorMessageToUser: "some error message" });
```

on error response [root of issue is, what is clean way to get at the contents of _body?, or another way to pass back parameters in Express?]

```
{
  _body: "{"errorMessageToUser":"some error message."}",
  headers: Headers,
  ok: false,
  status: 401,
  statusText: "Unauthorized"...
}
```

on success response

```
{ group: "asdf", password: "asdf, "username: "asdf" }
```

--end result

I want to be able to get to the errorMessageToUser in an error response, right now the only way is to open up body, convert that string to json, pull out the errorMessage, and strip the quotes off it - very dirty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a solution I am just changing the statusText to the error message I want and routing that to the ui for the user.

```
    res.statusMessage = "custom error message to user";
    return res.status(401).end();
```